# Em que ordem o método init() é invocado na linguagem Go?

Tags: golang, runtime

Eu li alguns *posts* na internet sobre a chamada implícita do método `init()` mas não entendi direito em que ordem ele é invocado num programa escrito em linguagem Go, principalmente pelo fato de poder existir vários métodos `init()` num mesmo `package`.

Como faço pra garantir uma certa ordem predeterminada? É possível isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A liguagem GO tem uma forma bem propria de tratar inicialização de módulos/packages.

Existe uma descrição deste problema de inicialização em http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#initialization

Para simplificar veja este exemplo mostrando a Execução implicita e explicita na Linguagem GO

**Fonte:** main.go

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  cmds "./commands"
  initialization "./init"
)

var isInitialized = initialization.IsApplicationInitialized()

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("•• Invocando o método main\n")
  initialization.Configure()
  // Inicializando a Configuração para os Comandos
  cmds.InitializeCmdConfig()
}
```

**Fonte:** init/init.go

```
package init

import "fmt"

func IsApplicationInitialized() bool {
  fmt.Printf("•• Invocando o método IsApplicationInitialized\n")
  return true
}

func init() {
  fmt.Printf("•• Invocando o método init de init.go no package init\n")
}

func Configure() {
  fmt.Printf("•• Invocando o método Configure de init.go no package init\n")
}
```

Resultado da Execução:

```
•• Invocando o método init de init.go no package init
•• Invocando o método init de whatever.go no pacote commands
•• Invocando o método IsApplicationInitialized no package init
•• Invocando o método init em main.go
•• Invocando o método main
•• Invocando o método Configure de init.go no package init
•• Invocando o método InitializeCmdConfig de whatever.go no pacote commands
```

Segue abaixo uma explicação.

Podemos pensar no método init como sendo semelhante a um bloco estático numa classe Java (neste caso executado no processo de load da Classe pela JVM) mas não podemos assumir nada em relação a ordem implícita. O resultado acima foi obtido na versão 1.4.2 do GO no MAC OSX mas não dá pra garantir se será a mesma em outras versões. Dá pra garantir apenas o que está documentado.

Neste exemplo acima o runtime GO garante que o método `IsApplicationInitialized()` rodará antes do método `init()` existente em `main.go` e que este método `init()` será executado antes do método `main()` no mesmo fonte.

O método `init()` é sempre chamado num dado pacote independentemente se existe ou 
não um `main`, assim se fazemos o `import` de um pacote que tenha um método `init` 
este método será executado, mas sempre após aqueles métodos referenciados em declaraçõeso de variável de escopo global. Podemos ter também multiplos métodos `init()` num dado pacote e eles são executados, como já foi enfatizado, após as variáveis serem inicializadas.

É saudável que o programador **não faça nenhuma suposição** quanto a ordem 
que esses métodos sejam executados. No caso de precisar de uma ordem pré definida use a técnica mostrada acima quando inicializamos uma variável com a chamada de um
método: `var isInitialized = initialization.IsApplicationInitialized()`. Isso forçará a ordem de execução de um dado código antes de qualquer método `init` daquele pacote.

Utilize métodos `init` para inicializar tabelas de valores para uma dada API, por exemplo. Veja um exemplo de uso do método `init()` na [linha 480 do fonte bzip2.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/compress/bzip2/bzip2.go#L480)

Answer (score 5):

Este é um problema que nenhuma linguagem que eu conheço conseguiu resolver por conta própria.

Não há garantias da ordem de execução. Simples assim. O compilador até tenta fazer isto dentro de uma ordem que garanta que dependências sejam atendidas em sua plenitude mas não conte que tudo será feito corretamente, especialmente se houver dependências cíclicas.

Eu já vi linguagens que providenciam algum recurso para facilitar que o programador estabeleça manualmente a ordem desejada, mas mesmo isto pode ter seus problemas em determinadas situações.

O fato de ter uma ordem garantida automática ou manual não garante que tudo vá funcionar como se espera. E claro que uma forma automática é mais difícil de alcançar.

O correto é escrever códigos que não dependam da ordem de inicialização. Não escreva códigos em um `init()` que você precise de garantias de execução em determinado momento. A solução quando precisa de garantia explícita é escrever chamadas explícitas. Cada problema exigirá um solução específica.

O assunto é diferente mas a [leitura sobre construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) pode ajudar entender a dificuldade.

[Documentação](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization).

Comment: O Golang não suporta imports/dependencias ciclicas diretamente, e a ordem do `init` é determinada no próprio spec (https://go.dev/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution). Ele diz "Given the list of all packages, sorted by import path, in each step the first uninitialized package in the list for which all imported packages (if any) are already initialized is initialized. This step is repeated until all packages are initialized." E também diz: "... initialization behavior, build systems are encouraged to present multiple files belonging to the same package in lexical file...".